# HTTPI unable to pass array params

Tags: ruby, httpi

```
@request.url     = url
@request.headers = {"Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"}
@request.body    = {a: "1", b: "2", c: [{d: "3"}, {e: "4"}]}
```

The problem is that the server side could receive params like a or b, but each value of c is null, like `"c": [{"d": null}, {"e": null}]`. Any help will be appreciated.

[Solved] :)  The server use .net and I don't know what they did..

Comment: When using `x-www-form-urlencoded` there's no de-facto support for nested variables. You may be running up against limits in how these are encoded. If you can't use a flat structure can you use JSON?

Comment: @tadman JSON doesn't work for me. When I post request by postman with json headers it works. But it doesn't work with x-www-for-urlencoded.

Comment: So it works with JSON or it doesn't work with JSON?

Comment: @tadman It works with JSON.